# I just want to use time in this colum (novice)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-timestamp

```
CREATE TABLE Vitals
(
    Record_No   int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Patient_ID  int, 
    Date_Taken  DATE NOT NULL,
    Time_Taken  time(7) NOT NULL,
    Systolic    int, 
    CHECK       (Systolic > Diastolic),
    Diastolic   int,
    Heart_Rate  int CHECK (Heart_Rate > 30),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Patient_ID FOREIGN KEY (Patient_ID) REFERENCES Patients(Patient_ID)
);
```

But, I get an error

```
Time_Taken time(7) NOT NULL,
               *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

When I use `timestamp default systimestamp`
it works. All I need is the time for `Time_Taken` column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpvNz.jpg)

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a `time` data type, so it is a little unclear what you want to do.

Comment: What is your objective?

Comment: Both the DATE and TIMESTAMP data types would include both a date and time component, and could be input and displayed using military time. I don't understand why you have Date_Taken as a separate column from Time_Taken. Why would these be separate database columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the `TIME` data type as it is not the oracle defined datatype.

You can use the `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type to store time with date.

Supported data types in oracle are documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1841).